# How to set local page numbers in minipages

Tags: page-numbering, minipage

Good time of the day! How to set page numbers in minipages?
Please see the code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1 cm, bottom=1.5 cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{(B)}
Blah,blah,blah.
\vskip 0.2 cm
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\subsubsection*{First step.}
Some text1.
\vskip 5 mm
%\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Q5b1.png}
\end{minipage} 
}
%--
\hskip 0.5 cm
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\subsubsection*{Second step.}
Some text 2. 
\vskip 3 mm
%\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Q5b2.png}
\end{minipage} 
}

\vskip 0.5 cm
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\subsubsection*{Third step.}
Some text3. 
\vskip 3 mm
%\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Q5b3.png}
\end{minipage} 
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should shorten your code so that it is really a *minimal* working example!

Comment: I edited the example. Is it  o'k now ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a possible approach or good starting point. Of course, many details can be improved according to your real needs that cannot be identified from your original question. Here is the result...

**Output**

[image]
**Code**

The code is rahter self explained. In fact, I introduced the macro `\MNP` (reminiscent to the minipage) that does the job for you. The first argument is the block title, the second argument is the description. Note that the second argument is delimited by `\endMNP`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{%
        a4paper,
        top=1cm,
        bottom=1.5cm,
        left=1cm,
        right=1cm
        }

\usepackage{mwe}


\newcounter{pg}
\setcounter{pg}{1}


\long\def\MNP#1#2\endMNP{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{.47\textwidth}
        \subsubsection*{#1}
        \parskip.3em
        #2
        \smallskip\par
        \hfill{\footnotesize\bfseries\thepg}
        \addtocounter{pg}{1}%
        \end{minipage}}\hfill}



\begin{document}
\parindent0pt


\subsection*{(B)}
Blah, blah, blah.
\bigskip


%-------------------------
\MNP{Title of this block}
    Some very interesting description.

    Further notes to the previous description involved inside this block.
    Further notes to the previous description involved inside this block.
\endMNP
%-------------------------
% no empty line
%-------------------------
\MNP{First step.}
    Some text1.
    \medskip\par
    {\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}\par}
    Some description
    Some description
    Some description
    Some description
\endMNP
%-------------------------



\vskip1cm



%-------------------------
\MNP{Second step.}
    Some text1.
    \vskip5mm
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-b}\par
\endMNP
%-------------------------
\MNP{Another title.}
    Some text.
    \vskip5mm
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}\hfil
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}\par
\endMNP
%-------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is thepg? Where I can read about such morphing of counters?

Comment: The `\thepg` is the current value of the `pg` counter introduced in the code. To call its value, we use the prefix `the`, i.e., `\the<couner_name>`.

Comment: Thanks! Where I can read about this?

Comment: See here: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters

Comment: @RustamMamin: Any feedback is highly welcome and expected.

Comment: The feedback will be within several weeks.